# Elasticsearch: Return different document for hit

Tags: elasticsearch, neoscms

I have some documents that have some kind of parent/child relation. Think grouped/variant products of a shop system.

Now, if the user searches for the article number of a variant I'd like to have Elasticsearch return the parent document.

Is there a "simple" way to achive this?

Comment: Nevermind. In the end I was doing this after I retrieved my results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `inner_hits` definition on a nested, `has_child` or `has_parent` query and filter. The structure looks like this:

```
"<query>" : {
    "inner_hits" : {
        <inner_hits_options>
    }
}
```

See the detailed documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html)

Comment: The thing is, my documents do have only a conceptual relationship based on a property. My index does not reflect this relation.